# Relocating Objects when they Spawn on top of Eachother

Tags: c#, monogame

As stated in the title, I am writing a code where objects are spawning on top of each other. Is there a way to prevent this? Here is my code:

```cs
// Check if the enemy UFO leaves the screen
if (enemyUfoPos[i].Y > screenHeight)
{
    // Update UFOs position
    enemyUfoPos[i].Y = -200;
    enemyUfoRecs[i].X = rng.Next(1, 1720);

    // Decrease the players score
    playerScores[SHOOTER] += ufoPass;
}

// Assume UFOs collide with eachother
bool isColliding = true;

while (isColliding == true)
{
    enemyUfoRecs[i].X = rng.Next(1, 1720);
    isColliding = false;

    for (int j = 0; j <= enemyUfoRecs.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        if (i != j && enemyUfoRecs[j].Intersects(enemyUfoRecs[i]))
        {
            isColliding = true;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

If anyone could give me some advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you want to archieve:

```
bool isColliding = false;

do
{
    enemyUfoRecs[i].X = rng.Next(1, 1720);
    isColliding = false;

    for (int j = 0; j <= enemyUfoRecs.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        if (i != j && enemyUfoRecs[j].Intersects(enemyUfoRecs[i]))
        {
            isColliding = true;
        }
        break;
    }
}
while (isColliding == true)
```

The difference is in the do-while loop, with a do-while loop, it goes through the code at least once, and then look at the `while` check afterwards if it needs to be repeated again.